# Windows 10 button disappearing when mouse over

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-10

My app is a Universal Windows 10 app. How to do the same as in the post [Windows 8 button disappearing when mouse over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248924/windows-8-button-disappearing-when-mouse-over), but in the code (VB preferably) ? Or where the XML code has to be put ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer from MSDN:
[On Mouse over / on Getting focus, The Button Disappers in windows 8 metro app, How to disable that effect?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5cf8f086-0a6c-4a81-aea8-000b726883cb/on-mouse-over-on-getting-focus-the-button-disappers-in-windows-8-metro-app-how-to-disable-that?forum=winappswithcsharp)